# React hooks: new state value not reflecting in setInterval callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function react component that has a counter that starts from 10000 and goes to 0.

I am setting a setInterval callback using useEffect hook during component mounting. The callback then updates the counter state.

But I don't know why, the `count` value never decreases. Each time the callback runs `count` is 10000.

(I am using react & react-dom version `16.8.3`)

Function component is as below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const Counter = () => {
  const timerID = useRef()
  let [count, setCount] = useState(10000)

  useEffect(() => {
    timerID.current = setInterval(() => {
      //count here is always 10000
      if (count - 1 < 0) {
        setCount(0)
      } else {
        setCount(count - 1)
      }
    }, 1)
  }, [])

  return <h1 className="counter">{count}</h1>
}

export default Counter
```

Here is the link to codesandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/l79pq1zoq7)

Comment: `setState()` is asynchronous...

Comment: Don't think that matters here.

Comment: `setCount(--count )` works. May or may not  be best approach?? It's a closure issue

Comment: set count as a dependency and use setTimeout will solve your pains :). because the next time rendering setTimeout will be called again when count has a new value

Answer (score 5):

You need to watch for changes in `count`, and also clean up your `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    timerID.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (count - 1 < 0) {
        setCount(0)
      } else {
        setCount(count - 1)
      }
    }, 100)

    return () => clearInterval(timerID.current);
  }, [count])
```

As @Pavel mentioned, Dan Abramov explains why [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Comment: Hi @Colin, Wouldn't that set new interval every time count is updated? I don't want this to happen. setInterval() should setup only once during mounting.

Comment: Yes it will. If you look at the blog post, there's a suggested `useInterval` hook which does a similar but more complex thing. TLDR; you need to set up and clear the interval on each re-render but it shouldn't be an expensive operation.

Comment: Got it!! Wondering how could I not find that blog post while searching for this on google... ><) Thanks anyway:) For now, I will go with using the "updater" form solution as mentioned in that post.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

**1) Include `count` in the dependencies**

This is not ideal, as it means a new `setInterval` will be created on every change of `count`, so you would need to clean it up on every render, example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    timerID.current = setInterval(() => {
      //count here is always 10000
      if (count - 1 < 0) {
        setCount(0)
      } else {
        setCount(count - 1)
      }
    }, 1)
    return () => clearInterval(timerID.current) // Added this line
  }, [count]) // Added count here
```

**2) Add the `count` in the `setInterval` callback function.**

This is the best approach for intervals, as it avoids, setting new ones all the time.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    timerID.current = setInterval(() => {
      // count is used inside the setCount callback and has latest value
      setCount(count => {
        if (count - 1 < 0) { // Logic moved inside the function, so no dependencies
          if (timerID.current) clearInterval(timerID.current)
          return 0
        }
        return count - 1
      })
    }, 1)
    return () => {
      if (timerID.current) clearInterval(timerID.current) // Makes sure that the interval is cleared on change or unmount
    }
  }, [])
```

Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-react-app-i4y39?file=/src/components/Counter.jsx:153-531)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring effect function when component mount as you said. So in scope in that time value store inside count is equal to 10000. That means every time interval function executes it takes count value from closure (10000). It is actually pretty tough to do it correctly. Dan wrote whole [blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) about it

Comment: Got it!! Wondering how could I not find that blog post while searching for this on google... ><) Thanks anyway:)